# Can I have Eclipse close all my projects when I exit?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to have Eclipse (3.5, if that matters) close any open projects I have before I exit my workspace. Is this possible?

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that these projects are remotely stored and it would be nice for that reason as well.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Can you not just disable the workspace?

Comment: Do you mean actually close projects or do you want eclipse to close all open files & "unexpand" projects? Seems a bit strange to actually close the projects.

Comment: The term "Close Projects" in Eclipse is actually Project Navigator > Rightclick Project > Close Project. I really can't imagine why you would need this on shutdown everytime (and reopen on startup!). This is clearly a misconception.

Comment: Odd that you guys can't see a use for this. I have a lot of projects (200 or more) that I have to keep in any given Eclipse environment I'm in.

Comment: I still do not understand why closing one workspace and opening a new does not work if you have the same project in both?

Comment: I could use this too.  I have an team plugin that endlessly prompts if the server isn't available.  If I forget to close the project before I go offline, and I startup eclipse, I can't use my workspace.  I've worked around this for now with multiple workspaces, but it's a bit of a pain.

Comment: Eclipse absolutely crawls when it starts up if I leave all of the projects open; it may take 15 minutes to even be responsive. I'd love to have a way to close the projects OUTSIDE of eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

<sup>Update 2011:</sup>

To actually close all projects on exit, you need a plugin similar to the one [mentioned in this thread](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-close-editors-automatically-with-work-2.html):

> I have implemented `shutdown()` of my plugin to close all the project and save
>   the workspace.

Note: today, you would implement the [`stop()` method of an `AbstractUIPlugin`](http://www.java-tips.org/images/stories/tips/others/eclipse/040606/image005.jpg), since `shutdown()` has been deprecated in Eclipse3.0+.
In it, you would [call `IProject.close()`](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-close-editors-automatically-with-work-2.html).

But you also need to set the [org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.CLOSE_EDITORS_ON_EXIT preference](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-close-editors-automatically-with-work-2.html) (the one I originally referenced below) for Eclipse to not try to restore those editors when you restart Eclipse again.
If you don't, you will get some exceptions like:

```
 Could not restore workbench layout
 Unable to restore editor - 
 createElement returned null for input element factory:   
   org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInputFactory.
```

---

<sup>Original answer back in 2010 ;)</sup>

This preference is close you need (from [this JavaTips](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-close-editors-automatically-with-work-2.html)) -- it does not close projects, but at least clean your workspace:

```
> General > Editors > Close editors automatically
```

> When any workspace of the eclipse is closed without closing all its editors and again opens the same workspace, it opens all the editors again which were opened at the time of closing.
>   This might cause slow down the starting of the eclipse.
>   So it is better to close all the opened editors before closing the workspace.
>
> All open editors can be closed automatically with the closing of the eclipse workspace.

[image: Close Editors Automatically]

Comment: +1: I also think this simple thing is what he actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can write a plugin to do it but since you're the first person who seems to need this, nothing like this exists.

Answer (score 0):

Is it Ok to add an answer several years later ... just discovered if you right click on the project and click close all unrelated projects, all the projects unrelated close anyway which is a quicker way of closing all your projects.

If thats helpful to anyone in future ? :-)